# Rearrange the characters in a string alphabetically using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I am looking to take a string field and rearrange the characters into alphabetical order.  For example, if it was a name field and the name was MICHAEL SMITH it would change to ACEHHIILMMST.

The main purpose is to look for duplicates in a field like name where someone could have made a typo and put in the name as MICHEAL SMITH or MICHAEL SMTIH.  Another option I thought of would be to assign a number value to each letter (1-26) and then if the sum of those values and the length of the name field are the same it would be considered a duplicate.  Problem with that is I do not know how to sum up numbers in a string field.

Also, I am using Oracle SQL so the functions would be based on those available.

Any ideas or at least places to start?

***EDIT***

I am not trying to ask for the code for how to do this, I am asking more if it is possible or not and if possible, what would my starting place be (types of functions, techniques, etc)

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: Would you consider using a stored function to do the rearranging?

Comment: I am not asking for code, I am asking for a starting point.  My knowledge of SQL is limited to running more basic queries so I am not always sure what it can and cannot do.

Comment: The SOUNDEX function comes to mind, but utl_match as mentioned in Joe's may be better.

Answer (score 4):

Check [utl_match](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_match.htm#ARPLS72002).  It can be used to measure the similarity of two strings.

```
select utl_match.edit_distance_similarity('MICHAEL SMITH','MICHEAL SMITH') from dual
85

select utl_match.edit_distance_similarity('MICHAEL SMITH','MICHELLE SMITH') from dual
79

select utl_match.edit_distance_similarity('MICHAEL SMITH','FRANKIE JONES') from dual
8
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, that looks like it would be a much simpler approach that I was not aware of.